# Performing Map in mongodb with C# driver

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I've got an object (for an instance `Person`) that I want to map.

I want to perform something preety much like LINQ's Select method and return `IEnumerable<ObjectId>` instead of `IEnumerable<Person>`.

I've also found that the method I've been looking for is called `map` in mongodb terminology.

is there any equivalent that can be used with the C# driver?

**Mongo Example:** the mongo function I'm talking about is

```
db.getCollection('Persons').find({}).map( function(p) { return p._id; } );
```

**Note:** I already know of

```
var persons= await personsCollection.Find(_ => true).ToListAsync();
return persons.Select(p=>p._id);
```

but I'm looking for something "tidier" and that is already part of the mongodb driver.

**EDIT**

I'm looking for something beyond projections.

my code currently looks like this:

```
var personsCursor= personsCollection.Find(_ => true);
var personsProjection = personsCursor.Project<Person>(Builders<Person>.Projection.Include(p => p._id));
var personsIds = await personsProjection.ToListAsync();
return personsIds .Select(p => p._id.ToString());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this purpose you can use [Projection](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.0/reference/driver/definitions/#projections);

From documentation:

> **Projecting Fields**
>
> Many times we don’t need all the data contained in a document. The
>   Projection builder will help build the projection
>   parameter for the find operation. Below we’ll exclude the “_id” field
>   and output the first matching document:
>
> ```
> var projection = Builders<BsonDocument>.Projection.Exclude("_id");
> var document = await collection.Find(new BsonDocument()).Project(projection).FirstAsync();
> Console.WriteLine(document.ToString());
> ```

And then, inside your own projection, you can specify which fields you need to return. If you go to the link above, you can find some documentation about the projection and mongo c# driver.

**EDIT:**

Also, you can use the `projection builder` to specify what you need to return:

```
var projection = Builders<BsonDocument>.Projection.Expression(d => d._id);
// and then put this projection to your query
var items = await collection.Find(new BsonDocument()).Project(projection).ToListAsync();
```

and now, each item should be represented only as `_id`.

Hope it will help.

Comment: I have came across projections and already using it but in order to get to an Enumerable of ObjectIds I still need to perform the Select method.

Answer (score 0):

to map properties in C#, you need to verify the official document from mongodb

```
https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.7/reference/bson/mapping/
```